# Multiple Instances of Google Translate On One Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-translate

On my page I have a top nav bar and a sticky nav that is toggled once the user moves past a certain point on the page. I am trying to embed Google Translate onto both the top nav and the sticky nav, but it seems like Google Translate can only be initialized once per page. I have tried the solution found here:

[Multiple Instances of Google Translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759756/multiple-instances-of-google-translate)

but the issue with that is that only the Google Translate embed has functionality only in the top nav, and not the sticky nav, and I need both of them to have a functioning Google Translate embed.

The way I think would be the best way to get this fixed for my situation is that I first:

1. On window load attach the Google Translate api script to the top nav element in a function
2. In new function, check that the user scrolls past a certain point of the page by using $(window).scrollTop() and then terminate the first function at that point.
3. Do the same as step two but reversed for when the user scrolls up past a certain point.

This is what im working with right now:

https://jsfiddle.net/jgg7ffwc/

Please keep in mind that only this function works right now but the rest of the functions fail when trying to terminate the first function:

```
$(window).load(function initializeGT() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'es', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE},'gls-element');
});
```

Any guidance would be very helpful, thank you.